# Notice: Undefined index: in /RendererFactory.php on line 66

Tags: magento-2.1

Getting an Undefined Index error in RendererFactory.php. When dumping out what its looking for string(39) "dev/front_end_development_workflow/type" string(5) "store" is what I get.

Now it's in the database in core_config_data. I'm running out of ideas at the moment!

Thanks